# Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a nonempty family of sets and $B$ is a set. Prove that $B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) = ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is Velleman's exercise 3.5.16.a:

Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a nonempty family of sets and $B$ is a set. Prove that $B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) = ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$.

And here's my proof of it:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Suppose $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F)$. Suppose $x ∈ ∪\mathcal F$. Now we choose an $A_0$ such that $A_0 ∈ \mathcal F$ and $x ∈ A_0$. Thus we have $x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$. Therefore, $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \Rightarrow x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$.

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$. We now choose some $A_0$ such that $A_0 ∈ \mathcal F ∪ \{B\}$ and $x ∈ A_0$. We now have two cases:

Case 1. $A_0 ∈ \mathcal F$. Since $x ∈ A_0$, $x ∈ ∪\mathcal F$. Ergo $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F)$.

Case 2. $A_0 ∈ \{B\}$. Since $x ∈ A_0$, $x ∈ B$ and therefore $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F)$.

From both cases we have $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F)$. Therefore $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \Leftarrow x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$.

Since $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \Rightarrow x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$ and $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \Leftarrow x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$ then, $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \iff x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$. Since $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \iff x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$, then $B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) = ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$.

Now I have ***three questions***:

1. Is my proof valid?
2. In the first part (i.e. $x ∈ B ∪ (∪\mathcal F) \Rightarrow x ∈ ∪(\mathcal F ∪ \{B\})$) I ignored "$x ∈ B$ " as a possible case, is there any problem with that?
3. From $A_0 ∈ \{B\}$ and $x ∈ A_0$, I concluded $x ∈ B$. Is that correct (I kind of doubt it)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your proof is almost valid, but...

2) ...you need to consider the case $x\in B$. However this isn't hard to fix, because $x\in B$ implies $x\in B=\cup\{B\}\subseteq\cup(\mathcal{F}\cup\{B\})$.

3) Yes, that is correct. If $A_0\in\{B\}$, then $A_0=B$. Consequently $x\in A_0$ means precisely that $x\in B$.

Comment: Could you please elucidate your answer to my second question more?

Comment: @Heptapod Sure. By the definition of union, we have $B=\cup\{B\}$. Then if $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are families of sets such that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{G}$, then $\cup\mathcal{F}\subseteq \cup\mathcal{G}$. This gives the inclusion because $\{B\}\subseteq\mathcal{F}\cup\{B\}$. Alternatively, if $x\in B$, then $x\in\cup(\mathcal{F}\cup\{B\})$ because there is a set in $\mathcal{F}\cup\{B\}$ (namely $B$), which contains $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have not examined your proof for correctness. $$ x\in \cup (B\cup (\cup F))$$ $$\iff (x\in B \lor x\in \cup F)$$ $$\iff \exists c\;(x\in c=  
 B\lor x\in c\in  F)$$ $$ \iff \exists c\;(x \in c\in \{B\}\lor x\in c\in F)$$ $$\iff \exists c\; (x\in c\in \{B\}\cup F)$$ $$ \iff x\in \cup (\{B\}\cup F).$$